# VxWorks compiling error

Tags: vxworks

I have a problem when I compile a little program in WindWriver Workbench 3.3. I'm making the first tutorial, HelloWorld, but when I launch the compiler, it return the next error:

```
C:\Windows\Temp\make45206.sh: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
C:\Windows\Temp\make45206.sh: C:\Windows\Temp\make45206.sh: line 1:
`if [ ! -d "`dirname "HelloWorld_partialImage/Debug/HelloWorld_partialImage.o"`" ];
then mkdir -p "`dirname "HelloWorld_partialImage/Debug/HelloWorld_partialImage.o"`";
fi;
echo "building HelloWorld_partialImage/Debug/HelloWorld_partialImage.o";
dld -tX86LH:vxworks69 -X -r5 -f 0x90,1,1  -o "HelloWorld_partialImage/Debug/HelloWorld_partialImage.o" HelloWorld_partialImage/Debug/Objects/HelloWorld/main.o   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727;C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\LIB;    && if [ "0" = "1" ];
then plink "HelloWorld_partialImage/Debug/HelloWorld_partialImage.o";
fi'
C:\WindRiver\utilities-1.0\x86-win32\bin\make.exe: *** [HelloWorld_partialImage/Debug/HelloWorld_partialImage.o] Error 2
```

I checked the `Makefile` but I don't see any error. Could you help me?

Comment: I mangled the error message when re-formatting it so that it would read a _little_ better -- just a note that I inserted all those newlines. It doesn't reflect the actual error message, but should hopefully be less painful to read.

Answer (score 1):

What is the contents of your `Makefile`?

I *think* the `;` separators on the pile of long pathnames here might be the issue:

```
\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\LIB;    && if [ "0" = "1" ];
```

`sh` will interpret the `;` as multiple commands to execute:

```
$ echo hello;echo hi
hello
hi
$
```

the `; &&` in this is going to confuse the shell, because both `;` and `&&` serve as command separators:

```
$ echo hello ; && echo hi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
$
```

Try replacing the `;` characters with `:` in whatever piece of the `Makefile` leads to those pathnames. (Or maybe spaces.)